# User reputation outage?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have been looking to the recent users tab and I was surprised that the first one made 24K+ reputation in 14 days! By looking to his profile, I can clearly see he has reputation dated from as old as April-May 2011.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730911/user3730911

Is this a reputation calculation outage or it is a problem with the user creation timestamp?

Comment: Probably an account merge

Comment: I have no idea what's going on with that account, but this is definitely not a bug - only a side-affect from the actions that were taken.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Quoting from [24,464 rep in 2 weeks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234485/24-464-rep-in-2-weeks) on Meta.SE:

> For reasons I won't go into out of respect for the privacy of the person involved, that account had to be re-created. This is a bit of a dodgy process, and so some information associated with it is inconsistent.

A new account was created and an old account merged into it. Because existing posts were moved over, the new user account inherited the reputation accrued through those posts.

Comment: One of the many times recently I wish we could close questions as cross-site duplicates.

Comment: @BradLarson: Sorry for that, I did not notice it was asked on SE meta. I cannot delete the question neither because there are answers

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou - Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying that your question is a problem (you wouldn't have known about the original on Meta.SE), just that we've had a few questions get asked in both places recently.

Comment: @BradLarson If they are truly duplicates, surely a migration would be suitable, and then closed as dupes? I know meta is a bit fragmented at the minute, so this might not be the best thing.

Comment: @Joe not really, because if we migrate this question, then we won't have a duplicate to close against the next time someone asks this question.  Since we can't close cross-site posts as dups it's better to have one on MSE and one on MSO.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Good point, having to migrate, and mark as dupe every time is a bit much.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Or worse; we would have converted Meta.SE into very much a dumpster of such dupes, especially after 2 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the registration date is 15 days old, you can check the reputation graph and see that most of the reputation has been earned back in 2011/2012

[image: Fancy red hand circle]

Don't worry. Data can be inconsistent on S.O due to migration and merge but you can easily see where and when the reputation has been earned for this "not so new" user.

Comment: That is what I did and why I asked the question Quoting from the question: `I can clearly see he has reputation dated from as old as April-May 2011.`

Answer (score -7):

No, that's *normally* impossible. Daily reputation limit is 200, you cannot earn more in one day - 14*200 gives 2800.

So based on above, I probably think he has merged his account to other, which has been created 14 days ago.

Comment: You can gain more than 200 rep a day (I am on 260 today). The rep cap excludes the accepted answer rep, bounties and association bonus.

Comment: I regularly gain over 2500 rep per week; that's not 25k in 2 weeks, but you *can* gain that much in 10, certainly.

Comment: Theoretically yes, but practically impossible, unless you manage to give more than 100 accepted answers per day for two weeks straight.

Comment: @GolezTrol If the answers were up voted then it may be less than 100

Comment: @09stephenb: no, that is *with* hitting the rep cap on upvotes. 103.16 answer accepts per day, or less if there are bounties involved.

Comment: @09stephenb: To get 24.464 in 2 weeks you need 1747 points per day. That is 1547 more than the rep cap, which means you would need 103 X 15 acceptance points per day to get that on top of the 200 rep cap. This calculation of course leaves other scores (favorited and such) out of the equasion, but I still think my 'more than 100' applies. So it's very unlikely that this happened, and Ty221 guess was right about the true cause.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Learn something new every day.

Comment: @GolezTrol Learn something new every day.